# Missing node_modules bin on PATH

Tags: intellij-idea, yarnpkg, iterm2

I have run the command
`yarn add -D jest` to install jest to my project.

This does successfully add jest to my node_modules

```
> find . -name jest

./node_modules/.bin/jest
./node_modules/jest
```

When I use iterm2 to run `jest` however I get the following output

```
> jest
zsh: command not found: jest
```

FWIW When I use the IntelliJ terminal it does work

```
> jest

Determining test suites to run...^C
```

What am I missing in the iterm environment to be able to have node_modules bin in my classpath depending on the current repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OS shell doesn't know about your locally installed **node_modules**, but IntelliJ terminal does. So if you want to run jest from outside of an IDE you should perform several additional steps.

The most common way to run locally installed packages is to define a separate script in the "scripts" section of your package.json file. Then you will be able to run it using the yarn/npm itself from any terminal. You can find an exact example in the Yarn [docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/).

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

```
yarn run test
```

Or you could install jest [globally](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global/) so it will be accessible from anywhere, but it's not a best practice.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I didn't realize IntelliJ was doing something extra here.